# error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(std::list<myclass*>, int, char**, char**)’ to ‘int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**)’

Tags: c++, database, list, stl, sqlite

I will try to be as succinct as possible. Well, I am given a project whose AIM is

1. Access Sqlite3 Database by using C++.
2. Make a class having member functions for executing different types of SQLite queries.
3. Once the above is done, make a List container using STL in main() and get each record stored as separate object in the list. So that, when a user tries to access the records of database with predefined SQLite queries, he will access the List container only and not the database.
4. Once the above is done in main()function, transfer all this code to one of the class member function. And call this particular function in main(), getting the exact output that we will get from AIM-(3)

So, working on this I created a Database foreign_key.db located in DBsqlite folder (PATH-/DBsqlite3/foreign_key.db).

NOTE: The **schema** of **emp_info** is as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE emp_info(
  SR_NO INT ,
  NAME CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  AGE INT(4) NOT NULL CHECK(AGE > 16),
  SEX CHAR (6) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS CHAR(70),
  EMPID INT NOT NULL CHECK(EMPID>300) UNIQUE,
  CARDID TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  SALARY INT CHECK(SALARY>10000) NOT NULL,
  MOBILE_NO INT(16) UNIQUE,
  EMAIL_ID TEXT(32) UNIQUE,
  BDT INT,
  PHOTO BLOB );
```

The entries in the **emp_info** table are as follows(I have deleted some columns to make it look better):

```
 SR_NO  NAME AGE  SEX   ADDRESS    EMPID  CARDID    SALARY    
  1     AAA  35  MALE   A1A2A3A4   301    1111AAA   11111    
  2     BBB  36  FEMALE B1B2B3B4   302    2222BBB   22222    
  3     CCC  37  FEMALE C1C2C3C4   303    3333CCC   33333    
  4     DDD  38  MALE   D1D2D3D4   304    4444DDD   44444    
  5     EEE  39  MALE   E1E2E3E4   305    5555EEE   55555    
  6     FFF  40  MALE   F1F2F3F4   306    6666FFF   66666    
  7     GGG  41  MALE   G1G2G3G4   307    7777GGG   77777    
  8     HHH  42  FEMALE H1H2H3H4   308    8888HHH   88888    
  9     III  43  FEMALE I1I2I3I4   309    9999IIII  99999`
```

I made the following program in C++ to achieve AIM-(1) and AIM-(2). The program below, also  creates a LIST CONTAINER to display the values as per sqlite query.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Employee{

    int SR_NO;
    int AGE;
    int EMPID;
    int CARDID;
    int SALARY;
    int MOBILE_NO;
    int BDT;

    char NAME;
    char SEX;
    char ADDRESS;

};

class sqliteDB{

private:
    int rc;
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg;
    const char *sql;

public:

    static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
    {
        int i;
        cout << "Number of args= " << argc << endl;

        for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
        {
            cout << azColName[i] << " = " << (argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL") << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    bool connectDB()
    {

        rc = sqlite3_open("/DBsqlite3/foreign_key.db", &db);
        if( rc )
        {
            cerr << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            sqlite3_close(db);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"\n\nDatabase opened successfully\n\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }


    bool allEmp()
    {   //NOTE- BELOW IS LINE 99
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE AGE>40; ", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        if( rc!=SQLITE_OK )
        {
            cerr << "SQL error: " << zErrMsg << endl;
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
};

int main()
{      

    list<sqliteDB> employee_info;
   // Read from database from below//

      for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
      {
         sqliteDB object2;
         object2.connectDB();
         employee_info.push_back(object2);
      }



    list<sqliteDB>::iterator i;
    for (i = employee_info.begin(); i != employee_info.end(); i++)
    {
        if (! i -> allEmp())
        cout<< i->allEmp() << endl;
     cout << " size of Object inside List is: " << employee_info.size() << '\n';
    }

}
```

**The Result of of above is :**

```
Database opened successfully

Number of args= 12
SR_NO = 7
NAME = GGG
AGE = 41
SEX = MALE
ADDRESS = G1G2G3G4
EMPID = 307
CARDID = 7777GGG
SALARY = 77777
MOBILE_NO = 9833446677
EMAIL_ID = abi@gmail.com
BDT = 07:08:1947PHOTO = NONE

Number of args= 12
SR_NO = 8
NAME = HHH
AGE = 42
SEX = FEMALE
ADDRESS = H1H2H3H4
EMPID = 308
CARDID = 8888HHH
SALARY = 88888
MOBILE_NO = 9833446688
EMAIL_ID = abj@gmail.com
BDT = 08:09:1947
PHOTO = NONE

Number of args= 12
SR_NO = 9
NAME = III
AGE = 43
SEX = FEMALE
ADDRESS = I1I2I3I4
EMPID = 309
CARDID = 9999IIII
SALARY = 99999
MOBILE_NO = 9833446699
EMAIL_ID = abk@gmail.com
BDT = 09:10:1947
PHOTO = NONE

SQL error: 21
size of Object inside List is: 1
```

Although, I am able to see 3 results for the sqlite query. But the object created in the list is just 1 (Note- in last line of result). I expected it to be 3 objects

I want the List container to store every valid record(row) as an individual list object in class Employee.User could access every field/column of the displayed record.

How can I achieve this ? I would really appreciate your help on this. I would highly appreciate if you show how it could be done with an example based on this question.

Thank you

**UPDATE-** Working on WhozCraig's suggested solution I changed the following things:

**Change-1** declaring another list container Employee:

```
list<Employee*> employee_info;
```

**Change-2** Putting this list in place of void *Notused

`static int callback(list<Employee*> employee_info2, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)`

**Change-3** Major changes in callback function

```
Employee *obj_emp = new Employee;
        int i;
        cout << "Number of args= " << argc << endl;

            obj_emp->SR_NO=(argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->NAME=(argv[1] ? argv[1] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->AGE=(argv[2] ? argv[2] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->SEX=(argv[3] ? argv[3] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->ADDRESS=(argv[4] ? argv[4] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->EMPID=(argv[5] ? argv[5] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->CARDID=(argv[6] ? argv[6] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->SALARY=(argv[7] ? argv[7] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->MOBILE_NO=(argv[8] ? argv[8] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->BDT=(argv[10] ? argv[10] : "NULL");

          employee_info2.push_back(obj_emp);

     cout << azColName[i] << " = " << (argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL") << endl;

        cout << endl;
        return 0;
```

And this the program in its entirety

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Employee{

public:

string SR_NO;
string AGE;
string EMPID;
string CARDID;
string SALARY; 
string MOBILE_NO;
string BDT;

string NAME;
string SEX;
string ADDRESS;

};

class sqliteDB{

private:
int rc;
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg;
const char *sql;

public:

//  list<Employee> employee_info2; //this line vector<Employee> *employee_info2; defines a pointer to a vector 
                                   //of type Employee and not a vector of type Employee pointers
    list<Employee*> employee_info2;


    static int callback(list<Employee*> employee_info2, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
     {
    Employee *obj_emp = new Employee;
        int i;
        cout << "Number of args= " << argc << endl;


            obj_emp->SR_NO=(argv[0] ? argv[0] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->NAME=(argv[1] ? argv[1] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->AGE=(argv[2] ? argv[2] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->SEX=(argv[3] ? argv[3] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->ADDRESS=(argv[4] ? argv[4] : "NULL");      
            obj_emp->EMPID=(argv[5] ? argv[5] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->CARDID=(argv[6] ? argv[6] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->SALARY=(argv[7] ? argv[7] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->MOBILE_NO=(argv[8] ? argv[8] : "NULL");
            obj_emp->BDT=(argv[10] ? argv[10] : "NULL");


          employee_info2.push_back(obj_emp);


            cout << azColName[i] << " = " << (argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL") << endl;

        cout << endl;
        return 0;
      }


bool connectDB()
{

      rc = sqlite3_open("/DBsqlite3/foreign_key.db", &db);
      if( rc )
      {
        cerr << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
      }
      else
      {
            std::cout<<"\n\nDatabase opened successfully\n\n";
      }
     return 0;
}


  bool allEmp()
  {
      sqliteDB object2;
      object2.connectDB();                 
      //NOTE- BELOW IS LINE 99
      rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE AGE>40; ", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
      if( rc!=SQLITE_OK )
      {
          cerr << "SQL error: " << zErrMsg << endl;
          sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
      }

      sqlite3_close(db);

    }
};

int main()
{     
   sqliteDB object1;
   object1.connectDB();
   object1.allEmp();
}
```

After compiling the Error i get is:

```
example1.cpp: In member function ‘bool sqliteDB::allEmp()’:
example1.cpp:99:95: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(std::list<Employee*>, int, char**, char**)’ to ‘int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**)’ [-fpermissive]
       rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE AGE>40; ", callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

what do I do next ? Kindly Help

Comment: For starters, how about actually returning something from `allEmp()` ? And what were you possibly trying to achieve with `for (int i=0; i<1; i++)` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig- the for loop displays the record just once. If it is not there then the display of result goes in infinite loop. Repeating the 3 records infinitely.

Comment: I have no idea what infinite loop you're referring to. The only thing that "loop" does is scope-protect `sqliteDB object2;` which is value-copied in to your `list<>` anyway. And of course the object created in the list is just one; the **sqliteDB** you put there. You need a *different list* for your records. Also, you may as well know now, no way are the fields of that structure correct.  What should be string members are `char`.

Comment: @WhozCraig- Thank you WhozCraig. I am editing my mistakes as we speak. The for loop in the list is redundant. I will change the char to string. what other mistakes have I made ?

Comment: @WhozCraig- Can you please show me an example, showing how it could be done ?

Comment: How what should be done? You have an enumerator callback already. That currently unused `void*` would be a fabulous place to pass a pointer to an object such as a `std::vector<Employee>` where you then populate. *Try it*.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a function pointer to the `sqlite3_exec` function of the wrong type. You need to change your callback's signature back to the way you had it.

```
static int callback(void *param, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
```

Then you should call `sqlite3_exec` appropriately. Something like this:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE AGE>40; ", callback, &employee_info2, &zErrMsg);
```

Finally, inside your callback you cast `param` back to the correct type.

```
std::list<Employee*>& employee_info2 = std::reinterpret_cast<std::list<Employee*>&>(*param);
```

Comment: I did as per your instruction but the actual error still persists. two Additional error came up: which are as follows:

`error: declaration of ‘std::list<Employee*>& employee_info2’ shadows a parameter
             std::list<Employee*>& employee_info2 = std::reinterpret_cast<std::list<Employee*>&>(*param);`


And 

    `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘reinterpret_cast’
             std::list<Employee*>& employee_info2 = std::reinterpret_cast<std::list<Employee*>&>(*param);`

Comment: You don't have to type the `std::` prefix because you specified `using namespace std;` Also, the shadow error sounds like you have a parameter and local variable with the same name.